# Grab text between identifiers while escaping a hyphen "-" in perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I'm attempting to grab the text of a line after the "A. " until the end of the line. I've tried:

```
perl -ne 'print if /A[.] /../\R/' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Where I thought the "\R" would match the end of a line. However when the line contains a hyphen "-", the output does not stop at the end of the line, instead prints the next lines until the hyphens stop.

An example line from **test.txt** that fails is as follows:

```
A. -rw-r-----, -r--------
```

The intended **test2.txt** output is:

```
-rw-r-----, -r--------
```

I'm getting the following bad output:

```
-rw-r-----, -r--------B. -rw-r--r--, -r--r--r--C. -rw-r--r--, -r--------D. -rw-r--rw-, -r-----r--E. -rw-------, -r--------: C
```

The following:

`perl -nle 'print if /A[.] (.*)/' test.txt > test2.txt` produces the same result as the command i provided above, but the output is still not ending at the end of the line when a hyphen is present.

Comment: Every line matches `/\R/`, so `print if /A[.] /../\R/;` is the same as `print if /A[.] /;`

Comment: Only after using `perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'print if /A[.] /../\R/'` I figured out what your code actually does: it prints every line between lines that match `/A[.] /` and lines that match `/\R/` (a generic newline). Not sure whether you used the flip-flop operator (`..`) intentionally.

Comment: `perl -nle 'print if /A[.] (.*)/' test.txt > test2.txt` produces the same result as the command i provided in the example, but the output is still not ending at the end of the line when a hyphen is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
perl -nle'print $1 if /A[.] (.*)/'
```

You could also use

```
perl -ne'print /A[.] (.*)/s'
```

or

```
perl -ne'print if s/^(.*?)A[.] //'
```

---

```
$ cat test.txt
A. -rw-r-----, -r--------
B. -rw-r-----, -r------w-
C. -rw-r-----, -r------x-
A. -rw-r-----, -r------y-
D. -rw-r-----, -r------z-

$ perl -nle'print $1 if /A[.] (.*)/' test.txt
-rw-r-----, -r--------
-rw-r-----, -r------y-

$ perl -ne'print /A[.] (.*)/s' test.txt
-rw-r-----, -r--------
-rw-r-----, -r------y-

$ perl -ne'print if s/^(.*?)A[.] //' test.txt
-rw-r-----, -r--------
-rw-r-----, -r------y-
```

Comment: `perl -nle 'print if /A[.] (.*)/' test.txt > test2.txt` produces the same result as the command i provided in the example, but the output is still not ending at the end of the line when a hyphen is present.

Comment: your suggestion: `perl -ne'print /A[.] (.*)/s' test.txt > test2.txt` does not solve the hyphen problem and produces a badly formatted output compared to my original command.

Comment: That's not true, as the answer now demonstrates.

Comment: The solutions I provided will only print `-rw-r-----, -r--------B. -rw-r--r--, -r--r--r--C. -rw-r--r--, -r--------D. -rw-r--rw-, -r-----r--E. -rw-------, -r--------: C` if that's the rest of the line, and you said you wanted to print the rest of the line.

Comment: The string had been converted to one line earlier in my script. Thank you.

Comment: @Matthew L. Abrasax, If A, B, C, D, E are not found anywhere else, it's super easy to fix. `perl -pe's/(?=[A-E])/\n/g'`

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. I used `pdftotext -layout` to print the lines individually.